# Change div content onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have div structure like this.

```
<div id="comparison_widgets" class="ui-widget row-fluid">
    <div class="portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" id="widget_0">
        <div class="portlet-header ui-corner-all">China</div>
            <div class="portlet-content" id="id_0" data-highcharts-chart="3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" id="widget_1">
        <div class="portlet-header ui-corner-all">India</div>
            <div class="portlet-content" id="id_1" data-highcharts-chart="3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" id="widget_2">
        <div class="portlet-header ui-corner-all">US</div>
            <div class="portlet-content" id="id_2" data-highcharts-chart="3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And each div with class `portlet-content` contains a pie chart. So, now when I click on any pie chart, its respective `portlet-header` div content should be changed to `XYZ`. For eg:- If I click China graph its name should be changed to XYZ.

Currently I'm doing it like this `$(".portlet-header").text("XYZ");` which changes all the portlet-header content. How do I do it correctly?

Comment: Actually I now notice that your html is not valid. You have too many `</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".portlet-content").on("click",function() {
  $(this).prev().text("XYZ");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.portlet-content').click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".portlet-header").text("XYZ");
});
```

Comment: Closest: _For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree._ - that will select a parent div, but not the sibling